# How can I change \ref s output from 5.1 to "some text"

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm currently developing a doclet which  translates javadoc to LaTeX.

I'm compiling the LaTeX document using `pdflatex` with a `sty` file I have from my school it generates a PDF document with links (red box) for all references
this means that a I don't need the *chapter.section* representation
I'm generating a label for example

```
\label{com.domain.package.Class}
```

when I  reference it I get something like `5.1`.

How can I change it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you exactly want. The `nameref` package (comes with `hyperref`) provides `\nameref` which gives the reference name instead of the number, e.g. the section title not the section number. There is also `\autoref` (`hyperref` package) which gives e.g. "Section 5.1".

For arbitrary link texts I would recommend to use `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` (both from `hyperref`) instead of `\label` and `\ref`.

There is also the `zref` package (written by the `hyperref` author) which gives you a lot of advanced cross-referencing options. See also the TeX FAQ [Referring to things by their name](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nameref).